# Angular equals based on one key in object

Tags: angularjs

I am looking to use angular.equals on two arrays which contain objects, but in order to be more efficient, I want to just compare based on a single id token within each object. What would be a good way to do this in Angular?

To give an example,
Array A1 = [obj1, obj2, obj3] and
Array A2 = [obj4, obj5, obj6].

I want say that A1 = A2, if obj1.id = obj4.id, and obj2.id = obj5.id and obj3.id = obj6.id

Comment: Just compare the property values. Without more detail on what you are specifically trying to do there isn't much else anyone can to to help. Please read [ask]

Comment: Arrays are defined with square brackets, `[]`; not braces `{}`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the map pattern to extract out the ids to compare, and then determine if the id lists are the same.

```
function compareById(a, b) {
    var aIds = a.map(function(x) { return x.id; } ).unique().sort();
    var bIds = b.map(function(x) { return x.id; } ).unique().sort();

   return aIds.length == bIds.length && 
          aIds.every(function(e,i) { return bIds.indexOf(e) == i; });
}
```